# Does the length of a string matter if being joined upon?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using bigquery to store user agents from web logs. We store a distinct list of all userAgents in a table.column called `UserAgent.userAgent`.

We have a need to join table `UserAgent` with other tables and we will use `UserAgent.userAgent` as the join key.

A user agent might look something like this:

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0`

That is 76 characters long, and that is one of the short ones.

I am wondering if it would be optimal to store and join upon a hash of the user agent instead. For example,

```sql
SELECT MD5('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0')
```

produces a value that is 16 characters long.

Is this an optimisation technique? Can BigQuery perform better if the strings being joined upon are shorter?

Comment: the shorter - the better. best to join on integers :o)

Comment: Yes, I know integers would be better but not an option in this case :)
Can you cite any justification for "the shorter - the better"? I don't doubt that you're correct but would appreciate seeing an explanation.